# Idiomatic usage of "of which"

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, relative-clauses

Taken from the Barron's SAT prep book:

> 1. "Ron liked to play word games, **of which** he found crossword puzzles particularly satisfying."

According to the answers this is an unidiomatic phrase that is too wordy and they fix it by adding a semi-colon and making the second clause into an independent one:

> 2. "Ron liked to play word games; he found crossword puzzles particularly satisfying."

My question: how is and which part of the first sentence unidiomatic, and how is it better than the second one?

In the first sentence the "of which" conveys the idea that the second clause is a part of the first, as opposed to the second sentence in which the semi-colon only expresses a connection between the two clauses.

Here's the exact copy of the question for those who are interested:

[image: Crossword puzzles]

Comment: Good question! From *this* native speaker's perspective, the first example sounds truly awful. But I can't see how to put this down to anything other than "idiomaticity", since there doesn't seem to be anything clearly distinguishing it from *"Ron has studied many Shakespearean plays, of which Hamlet is his favourite"*. Which I don't say is *truly* "unproblematic", but it's nowhere near as bad as the SAT example. And I expect there are other similar constructions that wouldn't bother me at all.

Comment: Unlike the sentence in the original question, this Hamlet sentence can be broken up into two separate sentences - Ron has studied many Shakespeare plats. Hamlet is his favourite *of them / of Shakespeare's plays."* That's why the single sentence with the relative clause works.

Comment: @FumbleFingers See Tunny's excellent answer below (beat me to it harrumph). Your sentence is fine because it could be reconstrued as: *Ron has studied many Shakespeare plays. Hamlet is his favorite **of them***

Comment: @tunny Aaargh you did it again! :)

Comment: @ Araucaria. I'm normally pretty slow on the draw, so let me enjoy my rare moment of glory.

Comment: @Araucaria: If you're satisfied that such arbitrary rearrangements enlighten you that's fine, but it doesn't resolve anything for me. I don't like your rephrased *Hamlet* example one little bit - so that can hardly explain to me why I'm only slightly put off by my version, whereas OP's original is the absolute pits.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your relative clause has a gap in it where [of which] has moved to the front. The antecedent for *which* is Sh plays. Your relative clause therefore is '***of which** Hamlet is his favourite* [***of Sh's plays***]'. The OP's antecedent is *word puzzles*. His relative clause with the gap in brackets: ***of which** he found crossword puzzles* [***of word puzzles***] *particularly satisfying*. That is literally the make-up of each clause ...

Comment: Could you verify for me that the expression in the question actually is *"he found crossword puzzles"*, and not _"he found **the** crossword puzzles"_? -- (I'm wondering if perhaps there's a typo in there, or in the SAT prep book, where it's missing the word "the".)

Comment: @F.E. I've added a screen shot of the question from the prep book. Answer choice (A) is stated as wrong though, so even if your version of it is better it doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: Thanks for that screen shot. :) -- Their reason for why option #A is bad -- that the expression "of which" is an unidiomatic phrase that is too wordy -- is really weird to me, for supplementary relatives often use that as their leading phrase. (It seemed to me that option #A is missing the "the" in "the crossword puzzles", and that's what was making it sound a bit off to my ear.)

Answer (score 2):

"Ron liked to play word games, of which he found crossword puzzles particularly satisfying."

Break this up into two separate sentences -"Ron liked to play word games. He found crossword puzzles  *of them /  of word games* particularly satisfying." The second sentence, which is what would be transformed into your relative clause just does not work; neither does the relative clause.

Comment: tunny (and @Araucaria ) -- Are you saying that the OP's #1 example (with the relative clause) is a bad sentence, or a good sentence?

Comment: @ F.E. - I said that it does not work. It is grammatically unsound.

Comment: Tunny, you need to make sure there is no space between the "@" symbol and my userid, else I won't get notified.

Comment: @Araucaria and tunny: So, just confirming here, both of you would consider the version with "the" in it to also be unsound: *""Ron liked to play word games, of which he found **the** crossword puzzles particularly satisfying."*  -- (Aside: tunny, notice how I put in Araucaria's name; actually, I typed "@a" and the input box filled in the rest for me.)

Comment: @F.E. I find it marginally better, and I find the RC *of which he found crossword puzzles [of word puzzles] particularly satisfying* marginally better. However I find the generic use of **the** with singular noun in *Ron liked to play word games, of which he found the crossword puzzle particularly satisfying* resolves the problem - the corresponding reconstituted RC is also better. *HOWEVER*, the specific difficulty with the original is not ...

Comment: @f.e. ... the (in)definiteness of the subject in the RC, it is the indefiniteness of the *antecedent*, "word games", used in a supplementary/non-restrictive clause. No? Supplementaries occur freely with definite antecedents, but less so with indefinite ones.

Comment: @f.e. ... so much the (in)definiteness of the subject in the RC, it is the indefiniteness of the *antecedent*, "word games", used in a supplementary/non-restrictive clause. No? Supplementaries occur freely with definite antecedents, but less so with indefinite ones.

Comment: @Araucaria Perhaps your colleagues (who are EFL instructors? linguists? teachers?) could provide their input on that version:  *"Ron liked to play word games, of which he found the crossword puzzles particularly satisfying."* It might be interesting (for us) to hear their opinions too.

Comment: @F.E. Yes, I will. As I said though, for me it's a case of awkwardness not ungrammaticality ...

Comment: @Araucaria So are you saying that the version *""Ron liked to play word games, of which he found the crossword puzzles particularly satisfying"* is grammatical and is standard English usage, but that it is awkward to your personal ear?

Comment: @F.E. Well it's a bit '?' if you get my drift, as opposed to the SAT's which I find a bit '#', but I wouldn't say it was ungrammatical. Problem is I can't make sense of the 'of which' in combination with an undelineated indefinite group such as 'word games'. How's this for you: "*Ron liked animals, of which he liked the giraffes in particular*" ? [btw it's EFL teachers all year, linguists for some of the year, and other students for most of the year. Oh yes, occasionally barstaff too!]

Comment: @Araucaria I was looking a bit at their so-called correct answer #D (which I would mark as being an unacceptable answer), and it seems to me that I'd only expect an EFL speaker to even consider something like #D. I'm seeing something like #D near one end of a cline, and as the language matures, then #D changes to become something like #A. For often a second sentence can become a subordinate clause which can then later become embedded as a relative clause within the first sentence. (cont.)

Comment: @Araucaria (cont.) For instance: _"Ron liked to play word games; he found the puzzles of word games particularly satisfying."_ **>** _"Ron liked to play word games, of which he found the puzzles particularly satisfying."_

Comment: @F.E. Yes, sounds plausible to me. Have to say that A sounds less off to me with the preceding sentences, so if I kind of squint at it a bit, it seems more felicitous. Maybe in the right context I'd find it much better altogether. 'puzzles of word games' seems a bit strange to me, but only a bit. I have to say that English SAT tests in general are awful. Really bad, and bring out the worst in poeple's writing, promote prescriptivism and dull people's natural linguistic judgement. But hey that's just my opinion! Grrr